# mvn release:prepare doesn't catch that I have modified files?

Tags: java, svn, maven-2, maven-plugin

Running on a Windows system, against a locally hosted VisualSVN server instance. I have `C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin` on my `PATH` variable so that I can simply run `svn` commands from the command line.

I'm attempting to prepare and perform a release on my Windows workstation, and I've noticed that `release:prepare` seems to miss the fact that I have modified files:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\...\workspace\project>svn status  
M       pom.xml
M       src\main\java\company\blah\SomeFile.java
```

Yet when I run mvn release:prepare, it doesn't seem to notice my modified files, and goes as far as attempting to check in the new POM and tagging the release:

> [INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
>   [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive status"
>   [INFO] Working directory: C:\Documents and Settings\blah\workspace\project-blah
>   [INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
>   What is the release version for "Project BLAH"? (com.vapps:project-blah) 0.0.1: :
>   What is SCM release tag or label for "Project BLAH"? (com.vapps:project-blah) project-blah-0.0.1: :
>   What is the new development version for "Project BLAH"? (com.vapps:project-blah) 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT: :
>   [INFO] Transforming 'Project BLAH'...
>   ...
>   ...
>   [INFO] Full run would be checking in 1 files with message: '[maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration'

(Note that this output is from running with `-DdryRun=true`, but I get the same result either way)

Does anyone have any idea why `mvn release:prepare` is missing that I have locally modified files? Could it be some awkward combination of running on Windows?

**Update**: appears to be related to [this bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-480) with the `scm` plugin.

Comment: As you say in your update, this looks to be a bug with the maven-scm-provider-svn, have you tried patching the plugin to correct the substring index? Does this fix it?

Comment: is the scm/developerConnection in the pom.xml correct?

Answer (score 1):

As the questioner pointed out in their update, this was http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-480 which has been fixed for at least two years.